# NEAR Indexer and 2FA secured wallet transactions

Tags: nearprotocol, indexer, near

In the Near, transactions signed by a 2FA-protected wallet are done in a special way (contract confirmation) and are not like regular transactions.
Signer and receiver id the same wallet.
Sample transaction:
https://explorer.near.org/transactions/9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY

How to work with them properly, where to find them in Indexer?
How do I get the data correctly, what contract and method the user signs?

Comment: Why do you think such transactions are not like regular ones? 2FA is a contract, all the transactions are the same. What to you mean by "find them in indexer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEAR Indexer for Explorer core contributor and maintainer here.

Looking at the transaction you've provided in your question https://explorer.near.org/transactions/9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY it was a `FUNCTION CALL` of the method `confirm`

And I believe your concern is that you cannot see the result of your transaction in the public [NEAR Indexer for Explorer database](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#shared-public-access) by querying the `transactions` table with the hash.

And by saying that 2FA transactions "are not like regular transactions" you mean the nature of [cross-contract](https://docs.near.org/docs/tutorials/contracts/xcc-receipts) calls involved.

Here's how to find out what is happening

1. First of all, let's look for your initial transaction and the Receipt ID it was converted to.

```
SELECT transaction_hash, converted_into_receipt_id FROM transactions WHERE transaction_hash = '9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY';

               transaction_hash               |          converted_into_receipt_id
----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------
 9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY | FP5UmXxdDBBicGkzgXXdhS28hxgBWVByFcqbwh25qHzN
```

According to the fact that this transaction you've sent was a confirmation of some `ft_transfer` call, we expect that there will happen a cross contract call to the `gems.l2e.near` contract.

We want to find all the receipts produced after execution of the receipt id `FP5UmXxdDBBicGkzgXXdhS28hxgBWVByFcqbwh25qHzN` (we found it in step 1)

2. Search for all receipts that were created during the execution of the initial one

```
SELECT produced_receipt_id FROM execution_outcome_receipts WHERE executed_receipt_id = 'FP5UmXxdDBBicGkzgXXdhS28hxgBWVByFcqbwh25qHzN';
             produced_receipt_id
----------------------------------------------
 9zem8CxJvdTHKkZKCc1pFhg4Ky4st6TBrQmE19gv4sAU
 3mtnLaGFYpXXzZ4H9vYczSXz9JbdS7XueSobDjQDAYb3
(2 rows)
```

3. So we have two other receipts, but we don't actually know what action they are containing. Let's find it out.

```
SELECT receipt_id, action_kind, receipt_predecessor_account_id, receipt_receiver_account_id, args FROM action_receipt_actions WHERE receipt_id IN ('9zem8CxJvdTHKkZKCc1pFhg4Ky4st6TBrQmE19gv4sAU', '3mtnLaGFYpXXzZ4H9vYczSXz9JbdS7XueSobDjQDAYb3');
                  receipt_id                  |  action_kind  | receipt_predecessor_account_id | receipt_receiver_account_id |                                                                                                               args
----------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3mtnLaGFYpXXzZ4H9vYczSXz9JbdS7XueSobDjQDAYb3 | TRANSFER      | system                         | shishkerin.near             | {"deposit": "12306467158537048105440"}
 9zem8CxJvdTHKkZKCc1pFhg4Ky4st6TBrQmE19gv4sAU | FUNCTION_CALL | shishkerin.near                | gems.l2e.near               | {"gas": 220000000000000, "deposit": "1", "args_json": {"amount": "2970000", "receiver_id": "hot1.l2e.near"}, "args_base64": "eyJyZWNlaXZlcl9pZCI6ImhvdDEubDJlLm5lYXIiLCJhbW91bnQiOiIyOTcwMDAwIn0=", "method_name": "ft_transfer"}
(2 rows)
```

Here we can see that Receipt `9zem8CxJvdTHKkZKCc1pFhg4Ky4st6TBrQmE19gv4sAU` is actually making a `FUNCTION_CALL` to `gems.l2e.near` signed by `shishkerin.near`

We can also look at args and find out that the method is calls is `ft_transfer` and arguments are `{"amount": "2970000", "receiver_id": "hot1.l2e.near"}`

(The other receipt `3mtnLaGFYpXXzZ4H9vYczSXz9JbdS7XueSobDjQDAYb3` is a transfer signed by `system` which is basically a cash-back for attached gas)

4. And just for sanity we'd like to know the execution status of the receipt

```
SELECT receipt_id, status FROM execution_outcomes WHERE receipt_id = '9zem8CxJvdTHKkZKCc1pFhg4Ky4st6TBrQmE19gv4sAU';
                  receipt_id                  |    status
----------------------------------------------+---------------
 9zem8CxJvdTHKkZKCc1pFhg4Ky4st6TBrQmE19gv4sAU | SUCCESS_VALUE
```

And I hope this answers your question.

---

- [Shared Public Access to NEAR Indexer for Explorer PostgreSQL database](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#shared-public-access)
- Decisions on what tables to query and what columns to get are made with [Database structure image](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#database-structure) in mind

Comment: thank you very much for a comprehensive answer and in no time at all. NEAR community is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @khorolets already mentioned, `receipts` table has `originated_from_transaction_hash` column which can help you to fetch all the receipts attributed to the transaction:

```
SELECT * FROM receipts WHERE originated_from_transaction_hash = '9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY';
```

```
                  receipt_id                  |            included_in_block_hash            |            included_in_chunk_hash            | index_in_chunk | included_in_block_timestamp | predecessor_account_id | receiver_account_id | receipt_kind |       originated_from_transaction_hash
----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------
 DiL4YA5iyKpsgkwdjdZkuiCatvKHmbVKPGAKpYJV1qS7 | AyX7umWGpR3RgQGnz4LAgTRnRGbF42krvAAjmXo4s4EV | 9VkhZdALu1EY6D2czKaKSV7qQZsLR6vxfAPXqBkgmAGg |              2 |         1644263681934508460 | system                 | shishkerin.near     | ACTION       | 9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY
 3mtnLaGFYpXXzZ4H9vYczSXz9JbdS7XueSobDjQDAYb3 | CyDT5XdZK8pKZM4VP559KxEXvUXTKaZbGVN3mVfoc5TX | FbfPdNLhYZEH3AncDiPa5qQZsaxCL8kfAtEaTV2geDi6 |              3 |         1644263680552610497 | system                 | shishkerin.near     | ACTION       | 9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY
 9zem8CxJvdTHKkZKCc1pFhg4Ky4st6TBrQmE19gv4sAU | CyDT5XdZK8pKZM4VP559KxEXvUXTKaZbGVN3mVfoc5TX | FbfPdNLhYZEH3AncDiPa5qQZsaxCL8kfAtEaTV2geDi6 |              2 |         1644263680552610497 | shishkerin.near        | gems.l2e.near       | ACTION       | 9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY
 FP5UmXxdDBBicGkzgXXdhS28hxgBWVByFcqbwh25qHzN | 5zvPFNeVytBNWfTzvmBaeCQtDrLuHfujKQqZ7qHhY4di | 4JngM4mhJnM9em6x8e7kJhyiSdPj1A9ZBzze9ZqJM8DP |              0 |         1644263679256841002 | shishkerin.near        | shishkerin.near     | ACTION       | 9uPvkdmcL4iNnWrHXZocf7NLAJUUVa4zSMrtFtJhrjcY
(4 rows)
```